# How to force Pages to explain a grammar correction

Tags: pages

See the picture below. I have typed something and Pages is telling me that there is an error.

I hove the mouse cursor over the word and no explanation appears.

Is there a way to force Pages to explain the error?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pages doesn't always give the best explanation but the explanation can be found in

```
Edit > Spelling & Grammar > Show Spelling & Grammar
```

[image]